# How to look up a .NET thread's stack size in using a tool?

Tags: .net, recursion, stack-overflow, callstack, process-explorer

I'm relatively new to .NET but I do understand that if infinite recursion happens in a Win32 thread, the thread stack would eventually run out of space and a stack overflow would happen.

Now i have a .NET application here, which might be doing infinite recursion in a scenario.

I was wondering if there a way to look up the current consumption of the managed thread stack using some tool like Process Explorer so that I can look into the details?

Comment: If you exhaust the stack, you'll get a StackOverflowException and the stack will give you info as to why that happened. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: If it's infinite recursion, it will crash before you have time to do anything (not so infinite after all!).

Comment: You have a bug in your code.  A really nasty bug, SOE is one of the worst possible exceptions.  You diagnose bugs with the debugger.  The Call Stack window shows the recursion.  Fixing the bug requires the tool you have between your ears, there is no substitute for that one.  Surely you already knew all this, it perhaps just takes a little push in the right direction.

Comment: It is a little more complicated than that, the software functionality requires that there should be a delay before the function gets called again. Which essentially means that i will have to wait for a long time before the Stack Overflow happens. I know i can see the call stack if i hook up Visual Studio, but i am interested in knowing the amount of space used on the thread stack at a particular moment in time. . How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you use Visual Studio IDE. You could use the [call stack window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx) you could see a lot of the functionality provided.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks. Would this let me see the amount of stack consumed for a particular thread at a given moment?